# New/Edit Form List column Validation formula for checkbox

Tags: sharepoint-online

If check box is selected, then there should be some data in the Namecolumn.
I have done it like below, but this doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A Yes/No field is a Boolean field, so no need to check explicitly for YES,
and blank testing is done with ISBLANK()

```
  =IF( [CheckBox] , IF( ISBLANK([Name]) , FALSE , TRUE ) , TRUE )
```

or

```
  =IF( [CheckBox] , NOT(ISBLANK([Name])) , TRUE )
```

Comment: what if I have to check the `Name column` first that if it contains data then the `check box` should be checked? otherwise error like  `select Check box`

Comment: Validation is very basic. You could use custom code in the [``PreSaveAction``](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/presaveaction-in-newform-aspx-in-sharepoint-2013-21106.aspx) function you can stick on the page with a CEWP or CSR code

Comment: can u pls help me with the formula for `If ColumnA has value and the checkbox is not checked then it should show error that **select checkbox**`

Comment: also can we write these formulas for lookup column?